# what is a hosting bandwidth?

Tags: hosting

i see always that there is confusion in this term, i [found this in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29#Bandwidth_in_web_hosting):

> In website hosting, the term "bandwidth" is often incorrectly used to describe the amount of data transferred to or from the website or server within a prescribed period of time, for example bandwidth consumption accumulated over a month measured in gigabytes per month. The more accurate phrase used for this meaning of a maximum amount of data transfer each month or given period is monthly data transfer.

How this is measured? if a user uploads a video, then the cost will be *upload + download x (number of views)* ?

What is the meaning of **unlimitied** in hosting bandwidth?

If there is a limit care about bandwidth, is this the **REAL** cause of using a Thread Based Server (limiting server ressources) instead of using an Event Driven?

ie: in event driven, there is no physical limit consumed compared to thread based, in thread based every thread will be created will consume memory and cpu ressources! not for event driven than solves the 10k problem, so i guess thread based is used to force machine to stop and waits for other clients to be replaced!

Comment: Not a programming question - voting to close as off topic.

Comment: there is also a language-agnostic which is not for programming!

Comment: Please explain how do you relate server resources (thread based vs. event driven) and bandwidth?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov added the explication :)

Comment: No. Language agnostic is for programming questions that apply to many different languages.

Comment: so Apache is not a language no :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, on **shared hosting** servers bandwidth is calculated from Apache web server logs, FTP service logs and maybe some other services.

Calculated traffic is a sum of filesizes transferred by apache etc, so it may not include traffic "outside" these "easy to calculate bandwidth" services. MySQL traffic may be not included for example.

Shared hosting means, that one server is running many websites and user (hosting customer) accounts.

---

On **dedicated servers** and **virtual machines** - traffic calculation usually is based on network driver/interface informations - its more precise and service-independent.

---

Meaning of unlimitied in hosting bandwidth - it may mean, that your hosting service is connected to Internet by network inteface, that is too slow, to exceed very big month transfer assigned to one user/customer of hosting provider.

---

Generally - hosting providers have to pay for transfer for their internet providers. Their bill is based not only on connection speed, like "home internet services".

Comment: so there is also a dedicated/shared servers difference!

Comment: so for every HTTP GET there is a sum! (if the user disables caching for example)

Comment: Im not sure about that HTTP GET. Its possible. You can take a look at apache logs and check if there is an information about bytes transferred by GET method.

Comment: i'll use Tornado (event driven server programmed using python), but it should me the same concept :)
thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Bandwidth includes uploads and downloads if I understand your question correctly. Any activity that requires sending data over the wire at the expense of the host would be considered bandwidth.

Using thread based or event driven architectures are ways to increase processing efficiency and to reduce blocking.

Comment: so less blocking is more clients, and more bytes exchanged in second